# How to configure Server Groups for OpenStack with Ansible

Tags: cloud, ansible, openstack

I was curious about what's the established method for configuring server groups (NOT security groups) with Ansible.  I looked at a list of the OpenStack Ansible modules here (http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_cloud_modules.html), but it doesn't seem like there's a Shade-based module that does that sort of thing.  Ultimately, the reason I'm asking is because I want to create groups of instances and configure them with anti-affinity rules.

Has anyone done that with Ansible before that might have some ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's an `os_server_group` module you can use.  However, you'll need to have some other process interrogate OpenStack to get the UUID's of the `server_groups` when you use `os_server` to spin up VMs and pass the UUID to `server_hints`.